# bioawk removed part of FASTQ header

Tags: bioawk

I used

```
bioawk -cfastx 'length($seq) > 1 {print "@"$name"\n"$seq"\n+\n"$qual}' in.fq.qz | gzip > out.fq.qz
```

in order to keep a particular read length, but this command shortened the header  from

```
@A00199:161:HF3JLDMXX:1:1101:5882:1063 2:N:0:CTGTAGCC+GAACAGGC
```

to

```
@A00199:161:HF3JLDMXX:1:1101:5882:1063
```

How is it possible to fix the `bioawk` command to remain the full command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bioawk -cfastx 'length($seq) > 1 {print "@"$name $comment"\n"$seq"\n+\n"$qual}' in.fq.qz | gzip > out.fq.qz
```

Note the addition of `$comment`, which is what follows the name on the first line of each entry.

Comment: Space was missing and I had to change it to `{print "@"$name " " $comment"\n"$seq"\n+\n"$qual}`